# plotting gnuplot with palette showing some labels

Tags: plot, gnuplot, color-palette

I am plotting data series with gnuplot with command:

```
p 'file.txt' u 1:2:3 with labels
```

and got the graph with a lot of labels as below

[image]

which looks messy. So, i use different command:

```
p 'file.txt' u 1:2:3 with points pt 5 palette
```

which showed beautiful graph with colour spectrum.
[image]

But it did not show the labels. Acutally I don't need to show all labels, but I would like to show lowest five and highest five values.

How can I mix these two commands so that I can show the graph with colour spectrum with 10 labels (5 for lowest five and another 5 for highest five). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The labels style accepts a `tc palette` option

Thus you can do

```
plot datafile u 1:2:3:3 with labels tc palette
```

For example, with the following data

```
1 1 30
1 2 40
2 2 30
2 1 35
3 3 10
3 4 15
```

using `plot datafile u 1:2:3:3 with labels tc palette` will plot

[image]

In order to filter to only the top 5 and bottom 5 numbers, you will need to do some pre-processing of your data outside of gnuplot.

Comment: hi thanks, but when i use that command, it showed "not enough columns for variable colour". Why it is happening?

Comment: Make sure that you are giving 4 columns as in my command, and not just 3.  Notice that I repeated the 3rd column.